Is it possible to remove side menu from webiste flow?
I am not sure how to ask correctly. I am making website, that has header and a side menu.
I have mentioned the code below to explain how I do it now. I want to know is there any way other way to make context of the webpage separate of side menu.
<body>
    <header>
        <p>LOGO</p>
        <a href="#">Home</a>
        <a href="#">Something</a>
        <a href="#">About us</a>
    </header>

    <div style="display: flex;">
        <div class="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Something</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        
        <div class="content">
            ACTUAL CONTENT
        </div>
    </div>
</body>


You can do this using JavaScript.


window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  console.log("here");
  document.body.innerHTML += 
   '<div style="display: flex;">'
  +'      <div class="menu">'
  +"          <ul>"
  +'              <li><a href="#">Something</a></li>'
  +'              <li><a href="#">Something</a></li>'
  +'              <li><a href="#">Something</a></li>'
  +"          </ul>"
  +"      </div>"
        
  +'      <div class="content">'
  +"          ACTUAL CONTENT"
  +"      </div>"
  +"  </div>"
});
<body>
    <header>
        <p>LOGO</p>
        <a href="#">Home</a>
        <a href="#">Something</a>
        <a href="#">About us</a>
    </header>

 
</body>



